# Add comments to Codename One build hints

Tags: codenameone

I'm starting a new project with Codename One. I was pleased to see that there have been significant improvements in Codename One. About the various ways to edit build hints (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-hints-editor.html), I would like to know if there is at least a way to insert comments in build hints.

The problem occurs because, sometimes, the customization of build hints is very complex. That's why it is appropriate to note the meaning and motivation of each build hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment in `codenameone_settings.properties` when editing it directly but that might be discarded by an editor as you work on it. This isn't something I tried in the past.